# Return less information for JSON parser errors

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Using asp.net core 3.1 for a web api, my problem is that when a request comes in with some invalid parameters, the framework produces an error message that I don't want returned in the response.

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|968ad6dd-4488d8bc10ec5760.",
    "errors": {
        "$.value": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $.value | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 15."
        ]
    }
}
```

Is it possible to change this error response to something else? Ideally, I'd want to reduce the verbosity and *not* return the error message ("The JSON value could not be converted to System.String").

app.UseExceptionHandler does not work. ExceptionMiddleware does not work because await _next(httpContext); does not throw an exception.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that one possible way is to play with this: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/5ff9ed68d1cf6c89d72d27a69b00ed0ecd34daed/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ModelStateInvalidFilter.cs

Either set _apiBehaviorOptions.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter or create a custom InvalidModelStateResponseFactory. Haven't tried it yet, but seems like a potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered an issue which is related to your problem. I had a post request that takes in a self defined class (RequestForm) as parameter that is constructed from the passed body.
When receiving a post request with a body in which there are errors (e.g. incorrect parameter type) I get too much information back.

How I handled it is instead of using the RequestForm and constructing it directly from the passed body. I just used Stream as parameter to receive the body as a string input, I then manually constructed the json object, finally I used the JsonSerializer to try to construct the RequestForm object. All of this happens inside a try catch block so you can catch the error and modify it to your needs.